# Haskell Recursion how to return an empty list and ignore recursively generated list

Tags: list, haskell, recursion, return

I'm writing a recursive function that builds a list, but has some conditions where, if met, the function should ignore the list that's been built so far and simply return an empty list on its own.

A simple example:

```
func (x:xs)
   | x < 10 = [x] ++ func xs
   | otherwise = ("return an empty list without the already built up list")
```

So if `xs` was a list `[1 .. 12]` then once it's built a list that's `[1..9]` then when it reaches `10`, it'll disregard the list it's built and just return an empty array `[]`, and **not** return an empty array that's passed back to the already built up list.

Is there a way to do this in Haskell? I've tried doing `return []` but it gave me the error:

> Couldn't match expected type ‘Int’ with actual type ‘[t0]’

Comment: `return` is not a keyword or special syntax. It's a function like any other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`return` is not a statement in Haskell, but even if it was it would not work anyway. Since due to recursion, you then return that list at that specific level.

It looks however that you simply want to know if *all* elements are smaller than `10`. If that is the case, you return the entire list, otherwise you return an empty list.

You can do that with:

```
func :: (Num a, Ord a) => [a] -> [a]
func xs | all (< 10) xs = xs
        | otherwise = []
```

or we can use recursion, and make use of `Maybe`:

```
func :: (Num a, Ord a) => [a] -> Maybe [a]
func [] = Just []
func (x:xs) | x < 10 = fmap (x:) (func xs)
            | otherwise = Nothing
```

We can then later convert the `Nothing` value with [**`fromMaybe :: a -> Maybe a -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Maybe.html#v:fromMaybe) to an empty list, although a `Maybe` might be better idea here, that allows us to differentatie between `func []` and `func [14]` for example.